# What does HHH000387 Hibernate warning mean?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-4.x

I have just updated to Hibernate 4.0 and am seeing the warning message :

`HHH000387: ResultSet's statement was not registered`

in my log files.  What does this mean, and should I be worried?

Comment: I'd like to know the answer to this question as well.

Answer (score 1):

I would not worry too much. In any case it looks like it is not in API's users hands to avoid this message. Logging is done in the org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceRegistryImpl. According [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/engine/jdbc/spi/JdbcResourceRegistry.html):

> The main function of a JdbcResourceRegistry is to make sure resources
>   get cleaned up.

Short look to the code tells, that such a message is logged in two situations:

1. ResultSet is registered via register-method, and statement is not registered.
2. ResultSet is released via release-method and statement is not registered.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source for the `JdbcResourceRegistryImpl` class that throws this error, I personally think having it log at WARN level is excessive; it should be INFO at most, unless there's a way to have all `Statement`s implicitly registered as part of a Hibernate/framework configuration.

It's not clear to me why a `Statement` should be registered, but if it's only a concern of the inner workings of Hibernate then routinely warning API users about it is a bug, right?

Answer (score 1):

This log message is a sign that `ResultSet.getStatement()` doesn't return the `Statement` which was originally asked to create the `ResultSet`.  (It may also indicate a memory leak.)  This can happen when using a JDBC wrapper, because there are two `Statement` objects: a wrapper/decorator and the underlying `Statement`.

In my project, I have my own JDBC wrapper for testing.  I fixed this warning in my `ResultSet` wrapper by ensuring that `getStatement()` returns the original `Statement` proxy (*not* a new proxy), rather than delegating to the underlying `ResultSet` (which would return the underlying `Statement`).

Any JDBC wrapper which is producing similar warnings could probably use a similar fix.  (A similar problem and fix may apply to the method `Statement.getConnection()`.)

By the way, there is a bug report for this logging here: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8210

Answer (score 0):

Did you configured connection pool?  I've got the same warning.  But if I added c3p0 in my maven dependency and get it correctly configured in hibernate.cfg.xml.  The warning disappears.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this warning was an indicator of huge performance leak! 
I have hibernate POJO objects with @oneToOne mapping. For one table it works fine and no warnings: it sends one request to MySQl server for getting all the records and then for one requests for each joined table.
For POJO where I'm getting this error (when no @oneToOne found): it sends one initial request for getting a list of all objects and then every time send new and new requests for mapped tables for each record.

So, let's say I have 2000 records in my test DB. And 3 @oneToOne mapped tables.

In a good case, it sends 1 request for getting a list and 3 requests for getting mapped tables.

In the case of a warning, it sends 1 initial request for getting list. Then send  3 requests for getting mapped info for each of 2000 records in DB! So 1999*3=5997 additional requests for each user for each call the @Controller (Spring MVC).

I hadn't noticed it while the web application and MySQL server were on the same server.