# Strange timeout while reading from mysql in Spring Boot

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

Notice the huge jump in time before the last two lines:

```
2018-06-15 00:22:38.263 DEBUG zicada-ws --- [nio-8080-exec-2] stractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer : Loading collection: [com.teletopia.tsip.dbhandler.models.CallFlow.moduleList#179]
2018-06-15 00:22:38.263 DEBUG zicada-ws --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.SQL                                  : select modulelist0_.CF_ID as CF_ID1_11_0_, modulelist0_.MID as MID2_11_0_, modulelist0_.CF_ID as CF_ID1_11_1_, modulelist0_.MID as MID2_11_1_, modulelist0_.description as descript3_11_1_, modulelist0_.tableName as tableNam4_11_1_, modulelist0_1_.answerCallPolicy as answerCa1_0_1_, modulelist0_1_.commonRecordingId as commonRe2_0_1_, modulelist0_1_.fileName as fileName3_0_1_, modulelist0_1_.nextMID as nextMID4_0_1_, modulelist0_1_.waitForComplete as waitForC5_0_1_, modulelist0_2_.customerSpecificModule as customer1_5_1_, modulelist0_2_.nextMID as nextMID2_5_1_, modulelist0_3_.AlertCallerWhenFree as AlertCal1_12_1_, modulelist0_3_.allowExtendedCall as allowExt2_12_1_, modulelist0_3_.announceCall as announce3_12_1_, modulelist0_3_.answerQueuePolicy as answerQu4_12_1_, modulelist0_3_.busyMID as busyMID5_12_1_, modulelist0_3_.busyRecordingType as busyReco6_12_1_, modulelist0_3_.connectedCallTimeout as connecte7_12_1_, modulelist0_3_.connectedCallWarning as connecte8_12_1_, modulelist0_3_.endDate as endDate9_12_1_, modulelist0_3_.givePosition as givePos10_12_1_, modulelist0_3_.givePositionInterval as givePos11_12_1_, modulelist0_3_.AnnounceCallMsgType as Announc12_12_1_, modulelist0_3_.queueingEnabled as queuein13_12_1_, modulelist0_3_.ringTonePolicy as ringTon14_12_1_, modulelist0_3_.smsText as smsText15_12_1_, modulelist0_3_.startDate as startDa16_12_1_, modulelist0_3_.useTrueANumber as useTrue17_12_1_, modulelist0_3_.waitMusic as waitMus18_12_1_, modulelist0_4_.answerCallPolicy as answerCa1_14_1_, modulelist0_4_.destinationNumber as destinat2_14_1_, modulelist0_4_.noAnswerTimer as noAnswer3_14_1_, modulelist0_4_.onBusyNextMID as onBusyNe4_14_1_, modulelist0_4_.onFailNextMID as onFailNe5_14_1_, modulelist0_4_.onNoAnswerNextMID as onNoAnsw6_14_1_, modulelist0_4_.onPassThroughNextMID as onPassTh7_14_1_, modulelist0_4_.passThrough as passThro8_14_1_, modulelist0_4_.useTrueANumber as useTrueA9_14_1_, modulelist0_5_.endDate as endDate1_9_1_, modulelist0_5_.illegalEntryMID as illegalE2_9_1_, modulelist0_5_.startDate as startDat3_9_1_, modulelist0_5_.timeout as timeout4_9_1_, modulelist0_5_.timeoutMID as timeoutM5_9_1_, modulelist0_6_.alertCallerOnOpen as alertCal1_15_1_, modulelist0_6_.closedMID as closedMI2_15_1_, modulelist0_6_.endDate as endDate3_15_1_, modulelist0_6_.manualState as manualSt4_15_1_, modulelist0_6_.openMID as openMID5_15_1_, modulelist0_6_.scheduleDefinition as schedule6_15_1_, modulelist0_6_.scheduleType as schedule7_15_1_, modulelist0_6_.startDate as startDat8_15_1_, modulelist0_6_.ClosedRecordingType as ClosedRe9_15_1_, modulelist0_7_.activeHgListId as activeHg1_6_1_, modulelist0_7_.addToConference as addToCon2_6_1_, modulelist0_7_.announceCall as announce3_6_1_, modulelist0_7_.answerCallPolicy as answerCa4_6_1_, modulelist0_7_.busyMID as busyMID5_6_1_, modulelist0_7_.connectedCallTimeout as connecte6_6_1_, modulelist0_7_.dtmfAcceptCall as dtmfAcce7_6_1_, modulelist0_7_.endDate as endDate8_6_1_, modulelist0_7_.huntGroupStrategy as huntGrou9_6_1_, modulelist0_7_.overflowMID as overflo10_6_1_, modulelist0_7_.overrideDestination as overrid11_6_1_, modulelist0_7_.ringTonePolicy as ringTon12_6_1_, modulelist0_7_.ringingTimeout as ringing13_6_1_, modulelist0_7_.startDate as startDa14_6_1_, modulelist0_7_.useTrueANumber as useTrue15_6_1_, modulelist0_7_.waitMusic as waitMus16_6_1_, case when modulelist0_1_.CF_ID is not null then 1 when modulelist0_2_.CF_ID is not null then 2 when modulelist0_3_.CF_ID is not null then 3 when modulelist0_4_.CF_ID is not null then 4 when modulelist0_5_.CF_ID is not null then 5 when modulelist0_6_.CF_ID is not null then 6 when modulelist0_7_.CF_ID is not null then 7 when modulelist0_.CF_ID is not null then 0 end as clazz_1_ from MID_To_Table modulelist0_ left outer join Announcement modulelist0_1_ on modulelist0_.CF_ID=modulelist0_1_.CF_ID and modulelist0_.MID=modulelist0_1_.MID left outer join CustomerSpecific modulelist0_2_ on modulelist0_.CF_ID=modulelist0_2_.CF_ID and modulelist0_.MID=modulelist0_2_.MID left outer join Queue modulelist0_3_ on modulelist0_.CF_ID=modulelist0_3_.CF_ID and modulelist0_.MID=modulelist0_3_.MID left outer join RouteCall modulelist0_4_ on modulelist0_.CF_ID=modulelist0_4_.CF_ID and modulelist0_.MID=modulelist0_4_.MID left outer join IVR modulelist0_5_ on modulelist0_.CF_ID=modulelist0_5_.CF_ID and modulelist0_.MID=modulelist0_5_.MID left outer join Schedule modulelist0_6_ on modulelist0_.CF_ID=modulelist0_6_.CF_ID and modulelist0_.MID=modulelist0_6_.MID left outer join HuntGroup modulelist0_7_ on modulelist0_.CF_ID=modulelist0_7_.CF_ID and modulelist0_.MID=modulelist0_7_.MID where modulelist0_.CF_ID=?
2018-06-15 00:22:38.264 DEBUG zicada-ws --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.l.p.e.p.i.ResultSetProcessorImpl     : Preparing collection intializer : [com.teletopia.tsip.dbhandler.models.CallFlow.moduleList#179]
2018-06-15 00:22:38.264 DEBUG zicada-ws --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.l.p.e.p.i.ResultSetProcessorImpl     : Starting ResultSet row #0
2018-06-15 00:22:38.265 DEBUG zicada-ws --- [nio-8080-exec-2] e.p.i.CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl : Found row of collection: [com.teletopia.tsip.dbhandler.models.CallFlow.moduleList#179]
2018-06-15 00:22:38.265 DEBUG zicada-ws --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.l.p.e.p.i.ResultSetProcessorImpl     : Starting ResultSet row #1
2018-06-15 00:22:38.266 DEBUG zicada-ws --- [nio-8080-exec-2] e.p.i.CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl : Found row of collection: [com.teletopia.tsip.dbhandler.models.CallFlow.moduleList#179]
2018-06-15 00:22:38.266 DEBUG zicada-ws --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.l.p.e.p.i.ResultSetProcessorImpl     : Starting ResultSet row #2
2018-06-15 00:22:38.266 DEBUG zicada-ws --- [nio-8080-exec-2] e.p.i.CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl : Found row of collection: [com.teletopia.tsip.dbhandler.models.CallFlow.moduleList#179]
2018-06-15 00:22:38.266 DEBUG zicada-ws --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.l.p.e.p.i.ResultSetProcessorImpl     : Starting ResultSet row #3
2018-06-15 00:22:38.266 DEBUG zicada-ws --- [nio-8080-exec-2] e.p.i.CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl : Found row of collection: [com.teletopia.tsip.dbhandler.models.CallFlow.moduleList#179]
2018-06-15 00:22:38.266 DEBUG zicada-ws --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.e.i.TwoPhaseLoad                     : Resolving associations for [com.teletopia.tsip.dbhandler.models.Announcement#component[callFlowId,moduleId]{callFlowId=179, moduleId=1}]
2018-06-15 00:22:38.266 DEBUG zicada-ws --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.e.i.TwoPhaseLoad                     : Done materializing entity [com.teletopia.tsip.dbhandler.models.Announcement#component[callFlowId,moduleId]{callFlowId=179, moduleId=1}]
2018-06-15 00:22:38.266 DEBUG zicada-ws --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.e.i.TwoPhaseLoad                     : Resolving associations for [com.teletopia.tsip.dbhandler.models.Announcement#component[callFlowId,moduleId]{callFlowId=179, moduleId=2}]
2018-06-15 00:22:38.266 DEBUG zicada-ws --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.e.i.TwoPhaseLoad                     : Done materializing entity [com.teletopia.tsip.dbhandler.models.Announcement#component[callFlowId,moduleId]{callFlowId=179, moduleId=2}]
2018-06-15 00:22:38.266 DEBUG zicada-ws --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.e.i.TwoPhaseLoad                     : Resolving associations for [com.teletopia.tsip.dbhandler.models.Schedule#component[callFlowId,moduleId]{callFlowId=179, moduleId=3}]
2018-06-15 00:22:38.266 DEBUG zicada-ws --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.e.i.TwoPhaseLoad                     : Done materializing entity [com.teletopia.tsip.dbhandler.models.Schedule#component[callFlowId,moduleId]{callFlowId=179, moduleId=3}]
2018-06-15 00:22:38.266 DEBUG zicada-ws --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.e.i.TwoPhaseLoad                     : Resolving associations for [com.teletopia.tsip.dbhandler.models.Queue#component[callFlowId,moduleId]{callFlowId=179, moduleId=4}]
2018-06-15 00:22:38.266 DEBUG zicada-ws --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.e.i.TwoPhaseLoad                     : Done materializing entity [com.teletopia.tsip.dbhandler.models.Queue#component[callFlowId,moduleId]{callFlowId=179, moduleId=4}]
2018-06-15 00:22:38.266 DEBUG zicada-ws --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.e.l.i.CollectionLoadContext          : 1 collections were found in result set for role: com.teletopia.tsip.dbhandler.models.CallFlow.moduleList
2018-06-15 00:22:38.267 DEBUG zicada-ws --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.e.l.i.CollectionLoadContext          : Collection fully initialized: [com.teletopia.tsip.dbhandler.models.CallFlow.moduleList#179]
2018-06-15 00:22:38.267 DEBUG zicada-ws --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.e.l.i.CollectionLoadContext          : 1 collections initialized for role: com.teletopia.tsip.dbhandler.models.CallFlow.moduleList
2018-06-15 00:23:09.883 DEBUG zicada-ws --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.r.j.i.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl   : HHH000387: ResultSet's statement was not registered
2018-06-15 00:23:09.883 DEBUG zicada-ws --- [nio-8080-exec-2] stractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer : Done loading collection
```

This occurs intermittently, but when it occurs, its always on that statement.

Callflow

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CallFlow")
public class CallFlow {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "CF_ID", nullable = false)
    private long callFlowId;
    @Column(name = "FirstMID")
    private Long firstMID;
    private String description;
    private Date startDate;
    private Date changeDate;
    private Date endDate;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "id.callFlowId", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Module> moduleList;

    public long getCallFlowId() {
        return callFlowId;
    }

    public void setCallFlowId(long callFlowId) {
        this.callFlowId = callFlowId;
    }

    public Long getFirstMID() {
        return firstMID;
    }

    public void setFirstMID(Long firstMID) {
        this.firstMID = firstMID;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public Date getStartDate() {
        return startDate;
    }

    public Date getChangeDate() {
        return changeDate;
    }

    public void setChangeDate(Date changeDate) {
        this.changeDate = changeDate;
    }

    public Date getEndDate() {
        return endDate;
    }

    public void setEndDate(Date endDate) {
        this.endDate = endDate;
    }

    public Set<Module> getModuleList() {
        return moduleList;
    }

    public void setModuleList(Set<Module> moduleList) {
        this.moduleList = moduleList;
    }

    public void setStartDate(Date startDate) {
        if (startDate == null)
            startDate = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        this.startDate = startDate;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        if (description == null)
            description = "";
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

Module

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MID_To_Table")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
        property = "tableName"
)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = RouteCall.class, name = "RouteCall"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Queue.class, name = "Queue"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Announcement.class, name = "Announcement"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Schedule.class, name = "Schedule"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = CustomerSpecific.class, name = "CustomerSpecific"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = IVR.class, name = "IVR")
})
public class Module {
    @EmbeddedId
    CallFlowModuleId id;

    String tableName;
    String description;

    public CallFlowModuleId getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(CallFlowModuleId id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTableName() {
        return tableName;
    }

    public void setTableName(String tableName) {
        this.tableName = tableName;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        if (description == null)
            description = "";
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

The log is with root set to DEBUG.

Does anyone have any idea what could be going on here, or any pointers in the direction of finding out ?

Profiling perhaps ?
The DBMS is mysql, just out of the box ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the discussion on this thread can answer your doubts - 
[What does HHH000387 Hibernate warning mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722300/what-does-hhh000387-hibernate-warning-mean)

Also, you can refer this link for more discussion on the ResultSet warnings here - [Hibernate ORM/ HHH-8210](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8210)